# Unit testing Flink Topology without using MiniClusterWithClientResource

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Fink topology that consists of multiple Map and FlatMap transformations.  The source/sink are from/to Kafka. The Kakfa records are of type `Envelope` (defined by someone else), and are not marked as "serializable".  I want to Unit test this topology.
I defined a simple SourceFunction that returns a list of `Envelope` as the source:

```
public class MySource extends RichParallelSourceFunction<Envelope> {

    private List<Envelope> input;

    public MySource(List<Envelope> input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);

    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<Envelope> ctx) throws Exception {
        for (Envelope listElement : inputOfSubtask) {
            ctx.collect(listElement);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {}
}
```

I am using MiniClusterWithClientResource to Unit test the topology.  I ran onto two problems:

1. I need to make MySource serializable, as Flink wants/needs to serialize the source.  As a workaround, I make `input` transient.  The allowed the code to compile.
2. Then I ran into the runtime error:

```
org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: The return type of function 'Custom Source' could not be determined automatically, due to type erasure. You can give type information hints by using the returns(...) method on the result of the transformation call, or by letting your function implement the 'ResultTypeQueryable' interface.
```

I am trying to understand why I am getting this error, which I was not getting before when the topology is consuming from a kafka cluster using a KafkaConsumer.  I found a workaround by providing the Type info using the following:

```
.returns(TypeInformation.of(Envelope.class))
```

3. However, during runtime, after deserialization, `input` is set to `null` (obviously, as there is no deserialization method defined.).

Questions:

1. Can someone please help me understand why I am getting the `InvalidTypesException` exception?
2. Why if MySource being deserialized/serialized?  Is there a way I can void this while usingMiniClusterWithClientResource?
3. I could hack some `writeObject()` and `readObject()` method in MySource. But I prefer to avoid that route. Is it possible to use some framework / class to test the Topology without providing a Source (and Sink) that is Serializable?  It would be great if I could use something like `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness` that I could pass as topology, and avoid the whole deserialization / serialization step in the beginning.

Any ideas / pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

1. "why I am getting the InvalidTypesException exception?"

Not sure, usually I'd need to see the workflow definition to understand where the type information is getting dropped.

2. "Why if MySource being deserialized/serialized?"

Because Flink distributes operators to multiple tasks on multiple machines by serializing them, then sending over the network, and then deserializing.

3. "Is there a way I can void this while using MiniClusterWithClientResource?"

Yes. Since the MiniCluster runs in a single JVM, you can use a static `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` to hold all of the `Envelope` records, and your `MySource` just reads from this queue.

Nit: Your `MySource` should set a `transient boolean running` flag to true in the `open()` method, false in the `cancel()` method, and check it in the `run()` method's loop.